# How do I enable .babelrc for JSS

Tags: jss

Coming from C#, I really like the below code

```
var prop = item.prop?.propname
```

Syntax.

This is supported in JS if you use the below code

```
@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining
```

Babel plugin.

However, if you just create .babelrc file JSS does not use this. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone named @aweber1 on slack #jss pointed me in the correct direction:

> The JSS React sample app is based on create-react-app (CRA)
>   https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app, which does not provide
>   any "official" mechanisms for overriding or extending any of the
>   configuration used by CRA. The formal recommendation from CRA is to
>   "eject" your app, which allows you directly modify webpack and other
>   configuration.
>
> However, there are also community-built libraries that allow you to
>   extend/modify the CRA config without ejecting. In particular: •
>   https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired •
>   https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts •
>   https://github.com/sharegate/craco

I was able to get craco to work, but it was a bit more involved.

1. npm i @craco/craco -D
2. npm i @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining -D
3. create .babelrc

> ```
> {
>   "plugins": [
>     "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"
>   ]
> }
> ```

4. update the scripts section of package.json switch

> ```
>   react-scripts start=> craco start
>   react-scripts build => craco build
>   react-scripts test=> craco test
> ```

5. update /sitecore/definitions/config.js set: babelrc: true,
6. update /server/server.webpack.config.js set: babelrc: true,

Check that jss start and jss deploy files both work.